# How to type a property in a parent class with the children value type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance

I have 3 class, for the simplification, it's class A, B and C.

C inherit from B and B inherit from A. They share a same property `initialState`. The class A only declare the property `initialState`, the class B define `initialState` with a value, and class C define an `initialState`, it should use it own value + the one inherited from class B.

Here is my simple example:

```js
abstract class ClassA<T> {
    readonly initialState: T; // initialState takes type from the class generic
}

interface StateFromB {
    count: number;
}

type StateWithChildState<T> = T & StateFromB;

// Here I call classA with the Type from children (it will be classC) + state type of classB
abstract class ClassB<T> extends ClassA<StateWithChildState<T>> {
    initialState: StateWithChildState<T> = {
        count: 0
    } as const;
}

interface StateFromC {
    allItems: any[];
}

class ClassC extends ClassB<StateFromC> {

    initialState: StateWithChildState<StateFromC> = {
        ...super.initialState,
        allItems: []
    } as const;
}
```

But typescript throw an error in the initialState of classB
`'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ readonly count: 0; }'`. I understand why I have this error, but I can't find how to solve it.

How can I have my initialState in classB and classC and fully typed ?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjXelm) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Indeed, this approach solves what I'm trying to do, even if I would prefer not to use an extra parameter for the constructor but it looks like there is no other solution. Thanks a lot! I was not thinking about it